# Regex pattern for extracting subtitle stream number and language from FFMPEG

Tags: regex

How do I extract just `2` and `eng` from this line below using regex?  Would it require two regex patterns to catch?

```
Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:([0-9])\(([a-zA-Z]*)
```

group 1 will be 2 and group 2 will be eng

explanation:

`:` matches the literal character ':'

`([0-9])` matching group for one numeric character this is group 1

`\(` matches the literal character '('

`([a-zA-Z]*)` matching group for any length of alphabetical characters this is group 2